# How to filter data for just two tissue types from a large data set?

Tags: filtering, google-api-python-client

I am trying to filter this data set (sampleAnno$SMTSD) and this gives me a list of the tissue types that was collected from a whole data set. My problem is, I don't know how to specify any further than this. For example, this is part of the data set
[The Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dc72M.png)

I tried sampleAnno$SMTSD$"Pancreas", "Testis" and it gave me "Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): :1:28: unexpected ','
1: sampleAnno$SMTSD$"Pancreas",
^
Traceback:" I am really new to this and I have no idea how to begin this, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.